# .NET: Disposing a HashAlgorithm object

Tags: .net, hashalgorithm

Objects that derive from HashAlgorithm such as MD5CryptoServiceProvider have a Dispose() method, but it's private. Instead it has a Clear() method which "Releases all resources" used by it.

WTF?

Is this how to correctly dispose of a HashAlgorithm then?

```
var hasher = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

byte[] hashCode = hasher.ComputeHash(data);

hasher.Clear();
```

Someone wanna explain this one to me? :)

Comment: I recommend you to use another hashing algorithm too if you can as many deem the MD5 hash unsafe in certain applications. A good alternative would be the SHA-family, like SHA 256. They are available for use in .NET too.

Comment: Good call. I remember reading MD5 had been proved vulnerable a few years back. Geeze, this from Wikipedia: "On 18 March 2006, Klima published an algorithm[10] that can find a collision within one minute on a single notebook computer, using a method he calls tunneling."

Comment: FYI "why does is implement IDisposable in the first place?" is discussed over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083838/why-does-the-hashalgorithm-class-implement-idisposable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking with Reflector, the `Clear` method of `HashAlgorithm` simply calls the private `Dispose` method. The reason for exposing a method with name `Clear` was probably just that the designers of the class thought it would be a more suitable name for a hash algorithm. You see similar styles within other parts of the BCL, such as `Close` for `System.IO.Stream`. Also, best practice here is to use a `using` block, which will automatically call the private `Dispose` method when it's finished.

Comment: As mentioned by others, it's best to use a `using` block anyway, which simplifies the try-finally/dispose logic for you, and is recommended practice.

Comment: Also, note that reflection also shows that the Dispose method is simply zeroing out an internal array.  it's not even releasing the array (not setting to null), its calling Array.Clear.
It doesn't seem to do any unmanaged releasing of any handles or other.  i think that if one 'forgot' to dispose this class, there'd be no leak or issue other than a security issue of leaving a previous hash value behind in memory.

Answer (score 13):

While the `Dipose()` method is private, if you cast it to `IDisposable` you can gain access to it. As others have said, though, `Clear()` will call it for you.

A better approach, however, is to enclose the declaration and and assignment of the variable in a using() block:

```
byte[] hashCode;

using(var hasher = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
{
    hashCode = hasher.ComputeHash(data);
}
```

Answer (score -5):

You should let the GC handle that for you. That's it's job.

Some resources should be disposed of, like DB connections and file handles, so put those in a `using` block (C#). This isn't one of those cases, though.

Comment: Actually, HashAlgorithm (and thus MD5CryptoServiceProvider) *do* implement IDisposable, therefore they should be properly disposed, either by calling the Clear method or with a `using` block.

Comment: Just because the class implements IDisposable, doesn't mean it needs to be disposed of manually. To each his own, though.

Comment: No indeed, but the fact that it *does* implement IDisposable almost always strongly signifies that it ought to be manually disposed because it's doing some native interop inside. The GC will eventually get around to disposing it even if you don't explicitly call the method, but the time at which this occurs is not guaranteed to be soon

Comment: @Alex: Actually that's 100% incorrect. If it implements IDisposable, you are ALWAYS supposed to explicitly call Dispose(). While good design would say that the Finalizer on the class should call Dispose() if an error in your code failed to, there is nothing technically requiring that. If it implements IDisposable, call Dispose().

Comment: HashAlgorithm does implement IDisposable

Comment: @AdamRobinson do you dispose all `Tasks in your code?

Comment: FYI, whether it's needed and what it's doing is discussed over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083838/why-does-the-hashalgorithm-class-implement-idisposable