# Why does the HashAlgorithm class implement IDisposable?

Tags: c#, .net, hash, idisposable

While using `MD5CryptoServiceProvider` I found that it might need to be disposed since it inherits from `HashAlgorithm` class which implements `IDisposable`. However, [the example in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.md5cryptoserviceprovider) didn't dispose it.

My question is why `HashAlgorithm` class implements `IDisposable` ? Isn't hashing just some computations that take place in memory ? What kind of unmanaged resources might be used in hashing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a look at [sources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/md5cryptoserviceprovider.cs,80152d7eff9b1f70)

```cs
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical] // overrides public transparent member
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (_safeHashHandle != null && !_safeHashHandle.IsClosed)
        _safeHashHandle.Dispose();
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

It's disposing the internal `SafeHashHandle` instance, which is used to wrap the unmanaged resource (operation system handle) and calls `Dispose` from base `HashAlgorithm` class. You have to properly dispose and release this handle after usage

```cs
[System.Security.SecurityCritical]
protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
{
    FreeHash(handle);
    return true;
}
```

This method is override of abstract `ReleaseHandle()` method from base `SafeHandle` class. You can read more about this class at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle?view=netframework-4.8), basically this class is a wrapper to any operation system resource

> It contains a critical finalizer that ensures that the handle is
>   closed and is guaranteed to run during unexpected AppDomain unloads,
>   even in cases when the platform invoke call is assumed to be in a
>   corrupted state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Pavel. But can you please tell me which OS handle might be needed for Hashing ?

Comment: Also, do you think the example in the docs should've disposed the `MD5CryptoServiceProvider` object ?

Comment: `SafeHashHandle` is example of unmanaged handle, which is created by `P/Invoke` call, look at the following method in [sources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/utils.cs,87fdde3bac834a6f). Maybe it's not an OS handle, it's just unmanaged reference, which must properly released.

Comment: Yes, I think that in docs `MD5CryptoServiceProvider` should be disposed, because it's disposing the managed resources used by `_safeHashHandle` (if any) and call base class `Dispose`, according to sample above. All unmanaged resources will be released by CLR, since base `SafeHandle` has a [Finalize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.finalize?view=netframework-4.8) method